# Statistics of many body systems in pure states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, entropy

My understanding of describing a system in thermal equilibrium is that we introduce an ideal thermal reservoir for convenience and then imagine that the system+reservoir samples all states of constant energy with equal likelihood (ergodicity), which we idealize as an ensemble, from which we can derive all sorts of concepts like mean energy, temperature, entropy, etc.

For something like electromagnetic radiation in a cavity, what is sometimes done is that we imagine a whole bunch of modes, and that energy can be transferred between modes (presumably via the walls of the cavity). In this case the large number of modes acts as an ensemble and so we can talk about the temperature of the radiation in the cavity (assuming it has thermalized).

Now what happens if you consider the radiation (and walls) to be a quantum many-body system that exists in a particular pure state? In other words, to put N excitations in a mode of wavelength k, we act $a_k^\dagger$ $N$ times on the vacuum. In principle you can cook up a pure state that has exactly the same population distribution as a thermal state with temperature $T$ and entropy $S$. However, most treatments I have seen would still firmly place this pure state at zero temperature, and conclude that it's (von Neumann) entropy is zero. Is this indeed the case?

Comment: What you're thinking about is the difference between states defined as a coherent sum -vs- a decoherent sum :-? I wonder if the coupling of the modes to the cavity will "decohere" the system into a mixed state rather than a pure state (by "dissipating" off-diagonal elements) -- I think this might happen if the the modes are eigenmodes of the free theory but not the interacting theory.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. If you trace out the wall degrees of freedom, you definitely obtain a mixed state, and without the wall, you are not in an eigenstate anyway. But suppose we could just consider the radiation by itself, with some coupling between modes. Suppose then that $\left\langle\Psi| N_k | \Psi \right\rangle$ follows approximately a thermal distribution. Could we then speak of the system as having some temperature, entropy? Or is it still "cold"?

Comment: If I made a caricature of the problem (Single mode, 2 levels (fermionic), high temperature limit so approximately equal probabilities and "maximum" thermal entropy), you're asking about the entropy of $|\psi\rangle = \frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ vs $|\psi\rangle \langle\psi| =  \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle \langle0| + \frac{1}{2} |1\rangle \langle 1| $

Comment: I think that goes too far. Having a single mode is like classically asking what is the entropy of a single particle. I do require a large number of modes or particles or what not, and that their distribution is thermal, but that the many-particle state is still a pure state.

Comment: A thermal population isn't a distribution of photons between nodes - it's a distribution of system _states_ with Boltzmann probabilities. For a pure state you can't have a Boltzmann distribution, however you populate the photons in those modes. A thermal state is a mixed state which can't be expressed with a single ket.

Comment: @lionelbrits: I'm not sure why one cannot pose a similar question in the quantum mechanics of one mode (single "particle", but multiple levels). Maybe I don't understand the essence of your question then.

Comment: @user27118, I'm asking if that's too restrictive. Classically, if I have a container full of gas, then even though I am ignorant of the exact state of each particle, I can still talk about the temperature of the gas and a thermal distribution. 

What is sometimes done is take one representative particle from that gas, and treat it as your system, and the remaining particles as your thermal reservoir. You can then derive a Boltzmann distribution for the likelihood of that particle having energy E. One should be able to do the same with photons in a box, in a pure state.

Comment: @Siva, I'm not sure why not either :) I just think that with a single particle, not in an energy eigenstate, and  with no other particles to interact with, it's hard to talk about any sort of thermal equilibrium. There is also no natural ensemble.

Comment: @lionelbrits Ah, I think I see. You mean to take one particular cavity mode as a subsystem coupled to a reservoir consisting of all the other modes. But this is not a matter of perspective in QM. A quantum environment performs weak measurements on a system causing it to decohere; its interaction with the system is fundamentally different from coupling terms in a Hamiltonian.